# java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

Tags: java

line "int yes = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());" is causing me problems in my calculator. im quite new at eclipse so any suggestions on correcting the code will be great.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner  sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your first number");
        int nr1 = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter your second number");
        int nr2 = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter your sign (+ , - , /, *)");
        int yes = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        int ans =0;
        int j = 0;
        int reset =j;

        java.lang.String anvin =  sc.nextLine();

        if(anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("+")) {
            ans = nr1 + nr2;
        }
        else if(anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("-")) {
            ans = nr1 - nr2;
        }
        else if(anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            ans = nr1 * nr2;
        }
        else if(anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("/")) {
            ans = nr1 / nr2;
            System.out.println(ans);
        }
        if(anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is that problem?

Comment: Well looking at your output I'm guessing the third line is a *sign*? `+ , - , /, *` are not integers now are they

Comment: @MindPeace It says so in the question title...

Comment: when i enter      * Enter your first number
9
Enter your second number
6
Enter your sign (+ , - , /, *)
*"  i get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "*"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at Main.main(Main.java:12)"

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using `sc.nextInt()` instead of `Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing one of these lines where you enter a number.

```
String anvin =  sc.nextLine();
```

with

```
int anvinNumbers =  sc.nextInt(); //for example
```

It may not answer why your parsing of text isnt working but is hopefully a solution.

**Refactored code**

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main 
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    Scanner  sc = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner object created
    int ans = 0;

    //Inputs
    System.out.println("Enter your first number");
    int nr1 = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your second number");
    int nr2 = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your sign (+ , - , /, *)");
    String anvin = sc.nextLine();

    if(anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("+")) {
        ans = nr1 + nr2;
    }
    else if(anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("-")) {
        ans = nr1 - nr2;
    }
    else if(anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
        ans = nr1 * nr2;
    }
    else if(anvin.equalsIgnoreCase("/")) {
        ans = nr1 / nr2;
    }

   System.out.println(ans);

    }
}

}
```

Comment: with that code it gave me an error with "Int anvinNumbers =  sc.nextInt();" and  "java.lang.String anvin =  sc.nextLine();" and i got "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Int cannot be resolved to a type
 Duplicate local variable anvin

 at Main.main(Main.java:9)" when i ran it

Comment: This is fine but might work better using char's as opposed to strings if you are only taking in one character for +, - sign etc

Comment: @thatguy Was this the most recent edit? i messed up a lot there doing it in my head haha. Ill have a look for you again

Comment: yes with the most recent edit you did it still gave me errors.

Comment: @thatguy edited again, i just looked and i left a tonne of errors. Sorry

Comment: Its because i forgot this line "string anvin = sc.nextLine();" sorry doing this off the top of my head

Comment: awesome! thank you so much. it isn't giving me any errors now. its just not giving me the answer. i will figure that out on Monday as i have to go to my next class. thank you again for all the help

Comment: @thatguy no problem sorry for the rushed answer and the mistakes so thanks for being patient :)

Comment: no problem, sorry for having the issues in the first place, i think its amazing how you can do that off the top of your head.

Comment: `int` should be lowercase.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Good catch just seen that. Thanks

Comment: @thatguy reedited the whole thing so should hopefully give you what you need when you run it again.

Comment: @KyleT After entering the two numbers it gave me "0" and asked to reset "Enter your first number
9
Enter your second number
9
Enter your sign (+ , - , /, *)
0
To continue type yes

Comment: it wouldn't let me put in the sign i wanted to use

Comment: @thatguy Sorry for the late reply, i've updated it for you. Just a couple of variables in the wrong position.

Comment: @KyleT Its alright. I just posted another question and got help on it :) thank you for getting back to me though.